# Collect various data in a submit form with html table

Tags: jquery, html, grails, grails-2.0

I have a jsp page with a table (paginated and with order columns), a search field and other filter based on check boxes.
So that when I click on a button, it takes the pagination of the table, the order of the table, the value in the search field and eventually others parameters (check box) to perform the query.

At the moment the table has a pagination and ordering columns using a tag library that fill the link with the necessary data to perform the query. So that when I click to page 2 as example, it knows the order column.
But if I have other fields and checkbox to include in the query how can I do to collect all this information? Some kind of big form tag that includes all the data?

thanks

Comment: https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-queuemail-plugin/blob/master/grails-app/views/queueMail/_list.gsp#L60 https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-queuemail-plugin/blob/master/grails-app/controllers/org/grails/plugin/queuemail/QueueMailController.groovy#L77 https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-queuemail-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/org/grails/plugin/queuemail/validation/QueueMailBean.groovy#L100-L114

Comment: `big form tag that includes all the data` that you build yourself. Lego bits require you to put them together to make it into something useful :)