# Pass sort and order params to controller with submit button

Tags: grails, parameter-passing

I have a view which shows a table with several database registers. Each row of the table has a checkbox, so when it is checked and then the submit button is clicked some actions occur to that register.

The problem is that I have some sortableColumns in the view, and if I have the table sorted by, for example, date, when I press the submit button the page reloads and the sorting is lost.

I have observed that when the controller receives the submit the "params" variable does not contain sort, offset, order ... params.

I guess I could store these parameters in session and then recover them, or even pass them as hidden fields of the form. But, is there another more convenient way of doing this? Don't the "g:submitButton" or "g:actionSubmit" provide a way of passing these parameters?

Thanks.

Comment: `or even pass them as hidden fields` and what's wrong with that ? I don't think there is a wizard sitting on the receiving end of a grails application making up new stuff as people wish it do. You have to sometimes roll up sleeves and be a developer and do some real stuff

Comment: You could have saved the sarcasm. Some frameworks (perhaps more well-thought ones?) provide an easy way to do this, just wanted to know if Grails did also. Don't really like to write superfluous code, perhaps you do.

Comment: No offence intended, this is nothing new, besides you have not really given anything for anyone to give you anything definitive on. sort should have a default value and then overriden by the user when they I presume sort a column using g:sortable that passes in your existing params and gets updated accordingly. At the moment g:submitButton and g:actionSubmit is on about a search form I presume which should be also then using same params as your g:sortable  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42021662/collect-various-data-in-a-submit-form-with-html-table#comment71217607_42021662 here